# Which is the best position for a modifying phrase coming from an adverb clause?

Tags: sentence-structure, adverb-placement

1. I forgot to call my brother because I was writing that email. [full sentence]

if I wanted to change the adverbial clause to a modifying phrase, can I move it around the sentence?

2. [Writing that email], I forgot to call my brother.
3. I forgot [writing that email] to call my brother.
4. I forgot to call my brother [writing that email].

In sentence number 3, the modifying phrase is in the same place as the original adverbial clause, but the sentence sounds a little confusing to me.

Which ones are correct?

Comment: None of those work because when you change it to a modifying phrase, it takes on the meaning of "***while** I was writing that email*" rather than "because".

Comment: The biggest difference between the original "full sentence" and your alternatives isn't the *position* of the adverbial clause. It's the fact that the original includes that all-important conjunction ***because***. Without that, we have no reason to assume any connection beyond that of ***simultaneity*** (all we know is the writing and the forgetting occurred at the same time; not necessarily causally connected).

Comment: What research have you done? Have you searched this site for existing questions about the placement of modifiers? (There are quite a few.)

Answer (score 1):

"Writing that email, I forgot to call my brother."

Is the closest to being correct, because it will be understood that the email was taking your attention, and because of that you forgot to call. If you don't make that assumption the sentence doesn't make sense, and people tend to make necessary assumptions to ensure something does make sense.

As has been noted in the comments, you definitely need 'because' in the other examples.